# "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'youtube_dl'" only when starting script directly, but not when passing it as argument to Python executable

Tags: python, windows, pip, python-import, youtube-dl

I have to use **youtube-dl** for a program.
When I try to execute my program with the command `python downloader.py`, my porgram starts correctly.

But when I try to execute directly my script with the command `downloader.py`, I get the following error:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'youtube_dl'

I already tried the following commands to install correctly youtube_dl:

```
pip install youtube-dl
pip3 install youtube-dl
pip install --upgrade youtube-dl
```

but it doesn't resolve my problem.

I think it's because I can't import a module with `-` with Python 3 so I have to import it with `_` and Windows doesn't recognize it.

Comment: Start python(3) then type in import youtube_dl. If you get an error there is something wrong. Try installing python(3) -m pip install youtube-dl. You can also uninstall it before to make sure. Check your site-packages folder if you can find youtube_dl folder. When installed type in youtube-dl -v to see if it works.

Comment: @Tom-OliverHeidel When i go through python commands it works well

Answer (score 1):

Not all packages can be installed with pip. try -

```
sudo curl -L https://yt-dl.org/downloads/latest/youtube-dl -o /usr/local/bin/youtube-dl
sudo chmod a+rx /usr/local/bin/youtube-dl
```

as their [GitHub site](https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl) suggests

Comment: I'm on windows, unfortunately I cannot execute these commands

Comment: @Bastien They also provide a [windows.exe](https://yt-dl.org/downloads/2020.09.06/youtube-dl.exe) file. Try to download and install.

Comment: I get the same error, I think I have already properly installed the module

Comment: So maybe you are not running the script with the interpreter you think? it happens all the time. type 'python -V' in both places and look at the full location of the interpreter where (1) you installed the package (2) you ran the code

Comment: In both cases I interpret with python 3.8.3

Answer (score 0):

**I'm on Windows and I didn't want to download an exe file** (I already have Python, no need for the program which wraps the Python package)

So I installed the youtube-dl module using `pip install --upgrade youtube-dl`

To run it:

```
py -m youtube_dl <video url>
```

The -m tells the interpreter to start a module, called youtube_dl (notice the underscore)

For video url, just paste the url of that video

Tested on Windows 10 and Python 3.9

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this problem by an alternative >

```
python3 -m pip install --force-reinstall https://github.com/yt-dlp/yt-dlp/archive/master.tar.gz
yt-dlp URL
```